# How to read last element from Section in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if the div having class name as "divclass" contains anchor tag, if contains I have to execute some javascript code else nothing to do.

```
<div class="divclass">
      <span> something text</span>
      <a href="/"> Anchor tag</a>
      <span> something text 2</span>
      <a href="/"> Anchor tag</a>
    </div>
```

How can we do that with jquery?

EDIT: In above HTML it has last element as anchor tag, so I want to do something code here but in below HTML I don't have anchor tag inside div so I don't want to do anything.

```
     <div class="divclass">
              <span> something text</span>
              <a href="/"> Anchor tag</a>
              <span> something text 2</span>
<span> something text 3</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tagName` to get name of tag. It returns name of tag in uppercase format.

Try:

```
$(".divclass").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find(":last").prop("tagName") == "A") {
        //do something
    }
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WBDm/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
if($('.divclass').has('a')) {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
if($('.divclass a').length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No, I want to check if the last element in div is span or anchor if last element is span I don't want to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery last() function.

Check this [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bjJlBsDjjz5cVP5Rt8ny?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

> You need to check the if the last span in divclass has anchor tag? Right.

```
if($('.divclass span:last-child').find('a').length > 0) {
// your code here :)
```

Comment: No, I want to check if the last element in div is span or anchor if last element is span I don't want to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative;

```
if( $('.divclass>a:last').length !== 0 ) {
```

[A JSfiddle to test with](http://jsfiddle.net/S6f6b/1/).